# Calculate a result of an order with php, ajax and javascript, checkboxes don't work

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, mailto

I've just created a nice tool to calculate the result (add, multiply and send the total by email) for a generic bakery.

My problem is that I'm not able to get the value inside my checkbox inputs. I tried in a few way but the only value that I was able to get from the radio checkbox was 1 (I suppose that the very value is a "true"). Everything else is working but I still find it a little verbose.

Here's my code:

THE HTML (problem):

```
<fieldset>
                        <label>MEAT & CHEESE TRAYS</label><br>
                        <label>Executive Tray</label><br>
                        <label class='radiolabel'><input type="checkbox" name="Executive[]" value="45">Serves 10–15 people</label><br/>
                        <label class='radiolabel'><input type="checkbox" name="Executive[]" value="62">Serves 20–25 people</label><br/>
                        <label>Hospitality Tray</label><br>
                        <label class='radiolabel'><input type="checkbox" name="Hospitality[]" value="48">Serves 10–15 people</label><br/>
                        <label class='radiolabel'><input type="checkbox" name="Hospitality[]" value="65">Serves 20–25 people</label><br/>
                        <label>Meat & Cheese Nibbler</label><br>
                        <label class='radiolabel'><input type="checkbox" name="Nibbler[]" value="48">Serves 10–15 people</label><br/>
                        <label class='radiolabel'><input type="checkbox" name="Nibbler[]" value="65">Serves 20–25 people</label><br/>
                        <label>Sliced Cheese Tray</label><br>
                        <label class='radiolabel'><input type="checkbox" name="Sliced[]" value="48">Serves 10–15 people</label><br/>
                        <label class='radiolabel'><input type="checkbox" name="Sliced[]" value="65">Serves 20–25 people</label><br/>
                        <label>Cheese Nibbler</label><br>
                        <label class='radiolabel'><input type="checkbox" name="Cheese[]" value="48">Serves 10–15 people</label><br/>
                        <label class='radiolabel'><input type="checkbox" name="Cheese[]" value="65">Serves 20–25 people</label><br/>
                    </fieldset>
```

THE PHP (problem):

```
$value = implode(',', $_POST['Executive']);
$Body = "";
$Body .= "Here's the order from: ";

$Body .= "Executive Tray: ";
$Body .= $value;
$Body .= print_r($value);
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Hospitality Tray: ";
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From:".$email);
```

LINK: My code is up and working on this page:

http://wilsonpools.larchedigitalmedia.com/foxbakapp/

THE ENTIRE CODE (Ignore it, only for debugging purpose or for a suggestions)

THE HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Contact Form Foxs</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form id="calculatoform" role="form">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Contact Details</legend>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for='firstname'>Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name='firstname' id="firstname" placeholder="Enter name" required data-error="Please, insert your name">
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for='address'>Address</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id='address' name='address' id="firstname" placeholder="Enter name" required data-error="Please, insert your address">
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for='company'>Company</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id='company' name='company' placeholder="Enter name" data-error="Please insert your company">
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for='phonenumber'>Phone Number</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phonenumber" name='phonenumber' placeholder="Enter Your Phone Number" data-error="Please enter your phone number" required>
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for='email'>Email</label>
                    <input type="email" name='email' class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" data-error="Please enter your email" required>
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <div>
                <div class="cont_order">
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Place Your order</legend>
                        <fieldset>
                            <label>SANDWICH TRAYS</label><br>
                            <label>Small Sandwiches</label><br>
                            <input type="number" name="smallsan"><br>
                            <label>Large Sandwiches</label><br>
                            <input type="number" name="largesan"><br>
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset>
                            <label>MEAT & CHEESE TRAYS</label><br>
                            <label>Executive Tray</label><br>
                            <label class='radiolabel'><input type="checkbox" name="Executive[]" value="45">Serves 10–15 people</label><br/>
                            <label class='radiolabel'><input type="checkbox" name="Executive[]" value="62">Serves 20–25 people</label><br/>
                            <label>Hospitality Tray</label><br>
                            <label class='radiolabel'><input type="checkbox" name="Hospitality[]" value="48">Serves 10–15 people</label><br/>
                            <label class='radiolabel'><input type="checkbox" name="Hospitality[]" value="65">Serves 20–25 people</label><br/>
                            <label>Meat & Cheese Nibbler</label><br>
                            <label class='radiolabel'><input type="checkbox" name="Nibbler[]" value="48">Serves 10–15 people</label><br/>
                            <label class='radiolabel'><input type="checkbox" name="Nibbler[]" value="65">Serves 20–25 people</label><br/>
                            <label>Sliced Cheese Tray</label><br>
                            <label class='radiolabel'><input type="checkbox" name="Sliced[]" value="48">Serves 10–15 people</label><br/>
                            <label class='radiolabel'><input type="checkbox" name="Sliced[]" value="65">Serves 20–25 people</label><br/>
                            <label>Cheese Nibbler</label><br>
                            <label class='radiolabel'><input type="checkbox" name="Cheese[]" value="48">Serves 10–15 people</label><br/>
                            <label class='radiolabel'><input type="checkbox" name="Cheese[]" value="65">Serves 20–25 people</label><br/>
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset>
                            <label>SPECIALTY TRAYS</label><br>
                            <label>Breakfast Delights</label><br>
                            <input type="number" name="delights">$4.30 per person (2 pieces/person)<br>
                            <label>Bagel Tray</label><br>
                            <input type="number" name="bagel">$4.10 per person<br>
                            <label>Spinach Dip Platters</label><br>
                            <input type="number" name="spinach">$17.99 each<br>
                            <label class='radiolabel'><input type="checkbox"  name="alligatorbread" value="3">Alligator or Turtle Bread add $3.00</label><br/>
                            <label>Party Ideas</label><br>
                            <input type="number" name="party">$5.99 each<br>
                            <label>Sweet Treats</label><br>
                            <input type="number" name="sweet">$1.55 per person (1.5 pieces/person)<br>
                            <label>Beverages & Extras</label><br>
                            <input type="number" name="soft">Soft Drinks (355mL)<br>
                            <input type="number" name="chocolate">Chocolate Milk (500mL)<br>
                            <input type="number" name="white">White Milk 2% (500mL)<br>
                            <input type="number" name="pickle">Huge Dill Pickle (Whole or Quartered)<br>
                        </fieldset>
                        <p id='totalPrice'>0</p>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
                <input type='submit' id='submit' value='Validate!'>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/formcalculations.js"></script>
    <script src="js/validator.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

THE JAVASCRIPT (JQUERY):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var grandtotal = function() {
        var total = 0;
        $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function(){
            total += isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val())) ? 0 : parseFloat($(this).val());
        });
        var small = $('[name="smallsan"]').val()*3.65;
        var large = $('[name="largesan"]').val()*4.05;
        var delights = $('[name="delights"]').val()*4.30;
        var bagel = $('[name="bagel"]').val()*4.10;
        var spinach = $('[name="spinach"]').val()*4.10;
        var party = $('[name="party"]').val()*5.99;
        var sweet = $('[name="sweet"]').val()*1.55;
        var soft = $('[name="soft"]').val()*1.25;
        var chocolate = $('[name="chocolate"]').val()*1.59;
        var white = $('[name="white"]').val()*1.39;
        var pickle = $('[name="pickle"]').val()*1.30;
        $("#totalPrice").html(small + large + total + delights + bagel + spinach + party + sweet + soft + chocolate + white + pickle);
        // console.log(small + large + total + delights + bagel + spinach + party + sweet + soft + chocolate + white + pickle);
    }
    // var grandtotal = grandtotal();
    $('input').change(function () {
        grandtotal();
    });

    $("#calculatoform").validator().on("submit", function (event) {
        if (event.isDefaultPrevented()) {
            formError();
            submitMSG(false, "Did you fill in the form properly?");
        } else {
            event.preventDefault();
            submitForm();
        }
    });

    function submitForm(){
        var firstname = $("#firstname").val();
        var address = $("#address").val();
        var company = $("#company").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var phonenumber = $("#phonenumber").val();
        var small = $('[name="smallsan"]').val();
        var large = $('[name="largesan"]').val();
        var delights = $('[name="delights"]').val();
        var bagel = $('[name="bagel"]').val();
        var spinach = $('[name="spinach"]').val();
        var party = $('[name="party"]').val();
        var sweet = $('[name="sweet"]').val();
        var soft = $('[name="soft"]').val();
        var chocolate = $('[name="chocolate"]').val();
        var white = $('[name="white"]').val();
        var pickle = $('[name="pickle"]').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "submitform.php",
            data: "firstname=" + firstname + "&email=" + email + "&company=" + company + "&phonenumber=" + phonenumber + "&address=" + address + "&small=" + small + "&large=" + large + "&delights=" + delights + "&bagel=" + bagel + "&spinach=" + spinach + "&party=" + party + "&sweet=" + sweet + "&soft=" + soft + "&chocolate=" + chocolate + "&white=" + white + "&pickle=" + pickle,
            success : function(text){
                if (text == "success"){
                    formSuccess();
                } else {
                    formError();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    function formSuccess(){
        $("#calculatoform")[0].reset();
        submitMSG(true, "Message Submitted!")
    }

    function formError(){

    }

    function submitMSG(valid, msg){
        if(valid){
            var msgClasses = "h3 text-center tada animated text-success";
        } else {
            var msgClasses = "h3 text-center text-danger";
        }
        $("#submit").removeClass().addClass(msgClasses).text(msg);
    }

});
```

THE PHP:

```
<?php

$errorMSG = "";

if (empty($_POST["firstname"])) {
    $errorMSG = "Name is required ";
} else {
    $firstname = $_POST["firstname"];
}

if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $errorMSG .= "Email is required ";
} else {
    $email = $_POST["email"];
}

if (empty($_POST["company"])) {
    $errorMSG .= "Message is required ";
} else {
    $company = $_POST["company"];
}

if (empty($_POST["address"])) {
    $errorMSG .= "Message is required ";
} else {
    $address = $_POST["address"];
}

if (empty($_POST["phonenumber"])) {
    $errorMSG .= "Message is required ";
} else {
    $phonenumber = $_POST["phonenumber"];
}

$small = $_POST["small"];

$large = $_POST["large"];

$delights = $_POST["delights"];

$bagel = $_POST["bagel"];

$spinach = $_POST["spinach"];

$party = $_POST["party"];

$sweet = $_POST["sweet"];

$soft = $_POST["soft"];

$chocolate = $_POST["chocolate"];

$white = $_POST["white"];

$pickle = $_POST["pickle"];

$value = implode(',', $_POST['Executive']);

$hospitality = $_POST["Hospitality"];

$nibbler = $_POST["Nibbler"];

$sliced = $_POST["Sliced"];

$cheese = $_POST["Cheese"];

$EmailTo = "mmaffei@larche.com";
$Subject = "Order from" . $firstname;

// prepare email body text
$Body = "";
$Body .= "Here's the order from: ";
$Body .= "Name: ";
$Body .= $firstname;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Company: ";
$Body .= $company;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Address: ";
$Body .= $address;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Phone: ";
$Body .= $phonenumber;
$Body .= "\n";

$Body .= "Executive Tray: ";
$Body .= $value;
$Body .= print_r($value);
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Hospitality Tray: ";
$Body .= $hospitality;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Meat & Cheese Nibbler: ";
$Body .= $nibbler;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Sliced Cheese Tray: ";
$Body .= $sliced;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Cheese Nibbler: ";
$Body .= $cheese;
$Body .= "\n";

$Body .= "SANDWICH TRAYS Small version: ";
$Body .= $small;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "SANDWICH TRAYS Large version: ";
$Body .= $large;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Breakfast Delights: ";
$Body .= $delights;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Bagel Tray: ";
$Body .= $bagel;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Spinach Dip Platters: ";
$Body .= $spinach;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Party Ideas: ";
$Body .= $party;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Sweet Treats: ";
$Body .= $sweet;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Beverages & Extras: ";
$Body .= "Soft Drinks: ";
$Body .= $soft;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Chocolate Milk: ";
$Body .= $chocolate;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "White Milk: ";
$Body .= $white;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Huge Dill Pickle: ";
$Body .= $pickle;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "For a gran total of: ";
$Body .= $small + $large + $delights + $bagel + $spinach + $party + $sweet + $soft + $chocolate + $white + $pickle;
$Body .= "\n";
// send email
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From:".$email);

// redirect to success page
if ($success && $errorMSG == ""){
   echo "success";
}else{
    if($errorMSG == ""){
        echo "Something went wrong :(";
    } else {
        echo $errorMSG;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your javascript `submitForm()` function you do not include the submission of the "Executive", "Hospitality", "Nibbler", "Sliced" or "Cheese" fields.

In your data string they do not exist...

```
data: "firstname=" + firstname + "&email=" + email + "&company=" + company + "&phonenumber=" + phonenumber + "&address=" + address + "&small=" + small + "&large=" + large + "&delights=" + delights + "&bagel=" + bagel + "&spinach=" + spinach + "&party=" + party + "&sweet=" + sweet + "&soft=" + soft + "&chocolate=" + chocolate + "&white=" + white + "&pickle=" + pickle,
```

This means those fields are never submitted to the PHP form handler, so that's why you can't get anything from them.

Instead of the complicated and verbose method of assigning every input to a variable and then crafting the data string yourself, why not try a simpler and more future proof method such as...

```
    var datastring = $("#calculatoform").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "submitform.php",
        data: datastring,
        success : function(text){
            if (text == "success"){
                formSuccess();
            } else {
                formError();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Great! Good catch!

Comment: I will give a try to the serialize method. Do I have to combine with the url or do I need only that to send data?

Comment: Is there anything similar in php to get a bunch of value?

Comment: All of those fields will still be assigned to `$_POST`. You can work with them just like a normal submission. Just `var_dump($_POST)` to see.

Answer (score 0):

The error should be inside your PHP.

For checkbox values, which have boolean as values, if you use that kind of check, you won't be able to enter inside the if when the checkbox is false.

Try to change your check for the checkboxes from this:

```
if (empty($_POST["checkboxName"])) {
    $errorMSG .= "Message is required ";
} else {
    $checkboxName = $_POST["checkboxName"];
}
```

to this:

```
if (isset($_POST["checkboxName"])) {
    $errorMSG .= "Message is required ";
} else {
    $checkboxName = $_POST["checkboxName"];
}
```

And you may have your issue fixed.

p.s. Here doc of empty from official PHP docs:

`Determine whether a variable is considered to be empty. A variable is considered empty if it does not exist or if its value equals FALSE.`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: For that particular value I only used

:$value = implode(',', $_POST['Executive']);

I used the other method for all the other value (to validate name, and so on)

Comment: is $_POST['Executive'] the value of a checkbox? or are they all the values?

Comment: it seems that in your post data in JavaScript there is no a parameter called 'Executive' are you sure you are sending it? and is that all the values of the checkboxes or only one?

Comment: MY HTML:
<label>Executive Tray</label><br>
                        <label class='radiolabel'><input type="checkbox" name="Executive[]" value="45">Serves 10–15 people</label><br/>
                        <label class='radiolabel'><input type="checkbox" name="Executive[]" value="62">Serves 20–25 people</label><br/>

THE PHP:
$value = implode(',', $_POST['Executive']);

No javascript because I don't need to validate that field

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why it is displayed like that. The point is that I used Executive as a name in the html and then I tried to get the result with php but not with javascript

Comment: nope you used `Executive[]` with brackets, and then you read for `Executive` without brackets.
Moreover it seems that you send data through an AJAX POST request with jQuery, and you passed as data a query string. In that query string there is not track of Executive

Comment: But now probably I've got what you're saying. You've just said that if I won't send the value with ajax but I will try to get only with php I won't be able to do anything, right?

Comment: yep correct! moreover implode in php accepts an array as second parameter. you should just use isset to check if it is set and then assign directly the boolean value to your php variable

Comment: Thank you very much @quirrimmo. Sorry if I can't give you a mark, but you gave me the right hint to solve my problem!